# Wordpress. Вывод постов в обратном порядке, но по отношению к выводимым, а не ко всем постам

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Есть свой тип записей. Я в один блок html вывожу 3 последних (новых) поста. А в другой блок мне необходимо вывести те же 3 поста, но в обратном порядке. Я пробовал использовать array_reverse(), но the_field() всё равно фигачит в обычном порядке.

```
<?php
$my_imgs = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_type'   => 'cases',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
) );
foreach( $my_imgs as $post ){ setup_postdata( $post );
?>
<div class="slide-card" style=" background-image: url(<?php the_field('main_img_case'); ?>);"></div>
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Уже облазил всё, перечитал как работает этот the_field, но так и не нашёл решения(если оно вообще есть). Help...

Comment: the_field здесь не при чем, да и array_reverse нормально работает

Comment: Я вроде понятно написал. array_reverse() работает и при выводе массива, я получаю то, что мне нужно. Но чтобы вывести данные мне нужно использовать the_field(), а она всё равно равно игнорит перевёрнутый массив и выводит в обычном порядке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывел данные в обычном порядке, а потом через JS и DOM поменял порядок